# Can't figure out why no trades are executed

Tags: logic, pine-script, trading

I'm trying to execute a long entry when the 3 conditions are true (redCandleDirection, isRsiLow, isUnderBollinger) but it won't work. I've tried manually setting them all to true and still no entries are executed. I'm fairly confident due to this that there's an error in my logic but I can't find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The conditions and when they are checked:

```
redCandleDirection = ((close[0] < open[0]) and (close[1] < open[1]) and (close[2] < open[2]) and (close[3] < open[3]) and (close[4] < open[4]))
isRsiLow = (d <= 10)
isUnderBollinger = (crossover(src, lower))
entryLong = false


isLongEntry(redCandleDirection, isRsiLow, isUnderBollinger) =>
    if (redCandleDirection)
        if (isRsiLow)
            if (isUnderBollinger)
                entryLong = true
            else
                entryLong = false
        else
            entryLong = false
    else
        entryLong = false
    entryLong



if isLongEntry(redCandleDirection, isRsiLow, isUnderBollinger)
    strategy.entry(id="Entry Long", long=true)
    strategy.exit(id="Exit Long", from_entry="Entry Long", qty_percent=100, limit=sma, stop=close[1])
```

The full code, if you need it:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © PatrickML
// @ ChuckBanger

//@version=4
strategy(title="Bollinger Bands w/ Limit and Trailing Stop", shorttitle="BB w/ L + TS", 
   overlay=true,  pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=50, initial_capital=1000.0)


length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=20, minval=1)
regular = input(title="Regular BB Or CBMA?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
mult = input(title="Multipler", type=input.float, defval=2.3, minval=.001, maxval=50, step=.1)
emaLen = input(title="EMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=20, minval=1)
emaGL = input(title="EMA Gain Limit", type=input.integer, defval=50, minval=1)
highlight = input(title="Highlight On/Off", type=input.bool, defval=true)

smaLen = input(title="SMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=9, minval=1)
sma = sma(close, smaLen)

direction = input(0, title = "Strategy Direction", type=input.integer, minval=-1, maxval=1)

strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(direction == 0 ? strategy.direction.all : (direction < 0 ? strategy.direction.short : strategy.direction.long))

//strategy.risk.max_drawdown(50, strategy.percent_of_equity)


///STOCH.RSI///
smoothK = input(3, minval=1, title="Stochastic %K Smoothing")
smoothD = input(3, minval=1, title="Stochastic %K Moving Average")
lengthRSI = input(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length")
lengthStoch = input(14, minval=1, title="Stochastic Length")
RSIprice = close
rsi1 = rsi(RSIprice, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)


calc_hma(src, length) =>
    hullma = wma(2*wma(src, length/2)-wma(src, length), round(sqrt(length)))
    hullma

calc_cbma(price, length, emaLength, emaGainLimit) =>
    alpha = 2 / (emaLength + 1)
    ema = ema(price, emaLength)
    int leastError = 1000000

    float ec = 0
    float bestGain = 0

    for i = emaGainLimit to emaGainLimit
        gain = i / 10
        ec := alpha * ( ema + gain * (price - nz(ec[1])) ) + (1 - alpha) * nz(ec[1])
        error = price - ec
        if (abs(error) < leastError)
            leastError = abs(error)
            bestGain = gain

    ec := alpha * ( ema + bestGain * (price - nz(ec[1])) ) + (1 - alpha) * nz(ec[1])
    hull = calc_hma(price, length)

    cbma = (ec + hull) / 2
    cbma

cbma = calc_cbma(src, length, emaLen, emaGL)
basis = regular ? sma(src, length) : cbma
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
cbmaColor = fixnan(highlight and not regular ? cbma > high ? color.purple : cbma < low ? color.aqua : na : color.red)
plot(basis, color=cbmaColor)
plot(sma, color=color.orange)
p1 = plot(upper, color=color.blue)
p2 = plot(lower, color=color.blue)
fill(p1, p2)

redCandleDirection = ((close[0] < open[0]) and (close[1] < open[1]) and (close[2] < open[2]) and (close[3] < open[3]) and (close[4] < open[4]))
isRsiLow = (d <= 10)
isUnderBollinger = (crossover(src, lower))
entryLong = false


isLongEntry(redCandleDirection, isRsiLow, isUnderBollinger) =>
    if (redCandleDirection)
        if (isRsiLow)
            if (isUnderBollinger)
                entryLong = true
            else
                entryLong = false
        else
            entryLong = false
    else
        entryLong = false
    entryLong



if isLongEntry(redCandleDirection, isRsiLow, isUnderBollinger)
    strategy.entry(id="Entry Long", long=true)
    strategy.exit(id="Exit Long", from_entry="Entry Long", qty_percent=100, limit=sma, stop=close[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started. You cannot use the `=` operator in a local block to reassign a value to a variable, otherwise you're creating a new local instance of that variable. Need to use `:=` instead.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © PatrickML
// @ ChuckBanger

//@version=4
strategy(title="Bollinger Bands w/ Limit and Trailing Stop", shorttitle="BB w/ L + TS", 
   overlay=true,  pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=50, initial_capital=1000.0)


length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=20, minval=1)
regular = input(title="Regular BB Or CBMA?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
mult = input(title="Multipler", type=input.float, defval=2.3, minval=.001, maxval=50, step=.1)
emaLen = input(title="EMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=20, minval=1)
emaGL = input(title="EMA Gain Limit", type=input.integer, defval=50, minval=1)
highlight = input(title="Highlight On/Off", type=input.bool, defval=true)

smaLen = input(title="SMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=9, minval=1)
sma = sma(close, smaLen)

direction = input(0, title = "Strategy Direction", type=input.integer, minval=-1, maxval=1)

strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(direction == 0 ? strategy.direction.all : (direction < 0 ? strategy.direction.short : strategy.direction.long))

//strategy.risk.max_drawdown(50, strategy.percent_of_equity)


///STOCH.RSI///
smoothK = input(3, minval=1, title="Stochastic %K Smoothing")
smoothD = input(3, minval=1, title="Stochastic %K Moving Average")
lengthRSI = input(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length")
lengthStoch = input(14, minval=1, title="Stochastic Length")
RSIprice = close
rsi1 = rsi(RSIprice, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)


calc_hma(src, length) =>
    hullma = wma(2*wma(src, length/2)-wma(src, length), round(sqrt(length)))
    hullma

calc_cbma(price, length, emaLength, emaGainLimit) =>
    alpha = 2 / (emaLength + 1)
    ema = ema(price, emaLength)
    int leastError = 1000000

    float ec = 0
    float bestGain = 0

    for i = emaGainLimit to emaGainLimit
        gain = i / 10
        ec := alpha * ( ema + gain * (price - nz(ec[1])) ) + (1 - alpha) * nz(ec[1])
        error = price - ec
        if (abs(error) < leastError)
            leastError := int(abs(error))
            bestGain := gain

    ec := alpha * ( ema + bestGain * (price - nz(ec[1])) ) + (1 - alpha) * nz(ec[1])
    hull = calc_hma(price, length)

    cbma = (ec + hull) / 2
    cbma

cbma = calc_cbma(src, length, emaLen, emaGL)
basis = regular ? sma(src, length) : cbma
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
cbmaColor = fixnan(highlight and not regular ? cbma > high ? color.purple : cbma < low ? color.aqua : na : color.red)
plot(basis, color=cbmaColor)
plot(sma, color=color.orange)
p1 = plot(upper, color=color.blue)
p2 = plot(lower, color=color.blue)
fill(p1, p2)

redCandleDirection = ((close[0] < open[0]) and (close[1] < open[1]) and (close[2] < open[2]) and (close[3] < open[3]) and (close[4] < open[4]))
isRsiLow = (d <= 10)
isUnderBollinger = (crossover(src, lower))


isLongEntry(redCandleDirection, isRsiLow, isUnderBollinger) =>
    _entryLong = false
    if (redCandleDirection)
        if (isRsiLow)
            if (isUnderBollinger)
                _entryLong := true
            else
                _entryLong := false
        else
            _entryLong := false
    else
        _entryLong := false
    _entryLong



if isLongEntry(redCandleDirection, isRsiLow, isUnderBollinger)
    strategy.entry(id="Entry Long", long=true)
    strategy.exit(id="Exit Long", from_entry="Entry Long", qty_percent=100, limit=sma, stop=close[1])
```